# how to give this type of shadow of a container in flutter?

Tags: css, flutter, dart, containers, shadow

I have a Simple screen with `GridView.builder` with `crossAxisCount: 3`, and in the `itemBuilder` I am returning `Container` with little shadow left, right, and bottom, but failed to achieve what I want.

[image of current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQYdo.jpg)

[image of the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZuUG.jpg)

```
GridView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    crossAxisSpacing: 15,
    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
    childAspectRatio: 2 / 3.3,
  ),
  primary: false,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 100,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black12,
            blurRadius: 5,
            spreadRadius: 5,
            offset: Offset(1, 1)),
        ]),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: The main difference I see is the black arcs (they look like loading animations) in the middle of each container. Is that what you're trying to achieve? If not, could you be more specific about what you're hoping for?

Comment: change offset eg. Offset(-1,1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I achieved what you are looking for based on the image you have provided by using a Card widget with elevation instead of a boxshadow. I also decreased the crossAxisSpacing a little to match the picture even more.

```
GridView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 20,
      childAspectRatio: 2 / 3.3,
    ),
    primary: false,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: 100,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: ya i was also tried this before, but i want little more shadow blurRadius: spreadRadius:
but unfortunately card doesn't have this property.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have given more blurradius and spread radius, just reduce it.Try this and adjust your blur and spread radius according to your view.

```
    BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 2,
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  offset: Offset(0, 0)),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).